# Regular expression - not allow space at the beginning

Tags: regex

Refer to my regular expression:

```
^(?!.*  )[^#+&\'\"\\\\]*$
```

I want to restrcit user to enter space at the beginning , for example:
(space)123  ---> invalid

How should I add it into the above regular expression?
Can someone help me?

Comment: should the final regex pattern match an empty string `""` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add an alternative to the lookahead:

```
^(?! |.*  )[^#+&\'\"\\\\]*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bEF4Zf/1)

The `(?! |.*  )` negative lookahead fails the match if a space appears right at the start of the string, or if there are double consecutive spaces somewhere after any 0+ chars (depending on the DOTALL option or regex flavor, any chars other than line break chars).

The same pattern can be written in a more linear way, as

```
^(?!(?:.* )? )[^#+&\'\"\\\\]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

> to restrcit user to enter space at the beginning

Even simpler using character class `[^\s]+?` which allows only non-space characters at the start of the string:

`^[^\s]+?[^#+&\'\"\\\\]*$`

Comment: This expression no longer matches an empty string. OP expression does.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I'll ask